# Сворачиваемые блоки jQuery

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте! Есть 4 фото на странице, есть 4 абзаца для каждого фото.
Вот нужно сделать что бы абзацы появлялись в зависимости от клика по фото.

```
        <a href="#about_1"><img id="author_1" src="{$template}/img/photo/1_.jpg"/></a>
        <a href="#about_2"><img id="author_2" src="{$template}/img/photo/2_.jpg"/></a>
        <a href="#about_3"><img id="author_3" src="{$template}/img/photo/3_.jpg"/></a>
        <a href="#about_4"><img id="author_4" src="{$template}/img/photo/4_.jpg" style="float: none;"/></a>

        <p id="about_1">Раз раз раз</p>
        <p id="about_2">Два два два</p>
        <p id="about_3">Три три три</p>
        <p id="about_4">Четыре четыре четыре</p>
```

Т.е. если открыт один блок, при клике на фото которое относится к другому блоку "первый" должен сворачиваться. Так же он должен сворачиваться при клике на фото которое относится к этому блоку.

Я так полагаю нужно использовать slideToggle. Но что то вот ни как не могу добиться нужного результата. Подскажите правильное решение пожалуйста :)

Comment: а к чему в документе 5 пар неуникальных айди элементов ?

Answer (score 4):

Делает делает то, что нужно, но до ума доводите сами

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtd/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="ru">
<head>
<title>Сворачиваемые блоки</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('p').hide();
        $('img').click(function(){
                $('p').slideUp();
                var must_shown = $(this).closest('a').attr('href').slice('#');
            $('p#'+must_shown).slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="#about_1"><img id="author_1" src="{$template}/img/photo/1_.jpg"/></a>
   <a href="#about_2"><img id="author_2" src="{$template}/img/photo/1_.jpg"/></a>
   <a href="#about_3"><img id="author_3" src="{$template}/img/photo/1_.jpg"/></a>
   <a href="#about_4"><img id="author_4" src="{$template}/img/photo/1_.jpg"/></a>

   <p id="about_1">Раз раз раз</p>
   <p id="about_2">Два два два</p>
   <p id="about_3">Три три три</p>
   <p id="about_4">Четыре четыре четыре</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Спасибо за голоса! Не забываем закрывать вопрос))